# What is the optimum limit for URL length? 100, 200+

Tags: asp.net

I have an ASP.Net 3.5 platform and windows 2003 server with all the updates.

There is a limit with .Net that it cannot handle more than [260 characters](http://forums.iis.net/p/1105360/1689855.aspx). Moreover if you look it up on web, you will find that IE 6 fails to work if it is not patched at above 100 charcters.

I want to have the rewrite path module to be supported on maximum number of browsers, so I am looking for an acceptable limit to which I can create verbose URL's.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A Url is path + querystring, and the linked article only talks about limiting the path. Therefore, if you're using asp.net, don't exceed a path of 260 characters. Less than 260 will always work, and asp.net has no troubles with long querystrings.

```
http://somewhere.com/directory/filename.aspx?id=1234
                                             ^^^^^^^- querystring
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ -------- path
```

Typically the issue is with the browser. Long ago I did tests and recall that many browsers support 4k url's, except for IE which limits it to 2083, so for all practical purposes, limit it to 2083. I don't know if IE7 and 8 have the limitation, but if you're going to broad compatibility, you need to go for the lowest common denominator.

Answer (score 3):

There is no length limit specified by the W3C, but look here for practical limits

http://www.boutell.com/newfaq/misc/urllength.html

pick your own limit from that.

Answer (score 3):

The default limit in IIS is 16,384 characters

But [IE doesn't support more than 2083](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/q208427/)

More info at [link](http://www.boutell.com/newfaq/misc/urllength.html)

Answer (score 2):

[This article](http://www.boutell.com/newfaq/misc/urllength.html) gives the limits imposed by various browsers.  It seems that IE limits the URL to 2083 chars, so you should probably stay under that if any of your users are on IE.

Answer (score 2):

Define "optimum" for your application.

The HTTP standard has a limit (it depends on your application):

> The HTTP protocol does not place any
>   a priori limit on the length of a URI.
>   Servers MUST be able to handle the URI
>   of any resource they serve, and SHOULD
>   be able to handle URIs of unbounded
>   length if they provide GET-based forms
>   that could generate such URIs. A
>   server SHOULD return 414 (Request-URI
>   Too Long) status if a URI is longer
>   than the server can handle (see
>   section 10.4.15).
>
> ```
>   Note: Servers ought to be cautious about depending on URI
>   lengths above 255 bytes, because some older client or proxy
>   implementations might not properly support these lengths.
> ```

So the question is - what is the limit of your program, or what is the maximum resource identifier size your program needs to perform all its functionality?

Your program should have a natural limit.

If it doesn't you might as well stick it as 16k, as you don't have enough information to define the problem.

-Adam

Answer (score 2):

Short ;-)

The problem is that every web server and every browser has own ideas how long the maximum is. The RFC for the HTTP protocol gives no maximum length. IE limits the get to 2083 characters, the path itself may be at most 2,048 characters. However, this limit is not universal. Firefox claims to support at least up to 65,536, however some people verified that on some platforms even 100,000 characters work. Safari is above 80,000 (tested). Apache server on the other hand has a limit of 4,000. Microsofts Internet Information Server has one being 16,384 (but it is configurable).

My recommendation is to stay below 2'000 characters in any case. This is not guaranteed to work with every browser in the world (especially not older ones), but it will work with all modern browsers. Further I recommend to use POST wherever possible (e.g. avoid using GET for FORM submits - if some users want to simulate a FORM submit via GET, make sure your application supports the desired parameters either via POST or via GET, but when you submit the page yourself via a button or JS, prefer POST over GET).

Answer (score 1):

I think the RFC says 4096 chars but IE truncates down to 2083 characters. Stay well under that to be safe.

Practically, shorter URLs are friendlier.

Answer (score 0):

More information is needed but for normal situations I would say try to keep it under 150 for sure. If for nothing else than pure ascetics, I hate when someone sends me a GI-NORMOUS link...

Are you passing values through the query string? I assume that is why you asked, correct?

Answer (score 0):

What is "optimum" anyway?

GET requests can be several kB in length, so this is entirely subjective.

I'd say - stay within the address bar length of a maximized 1024x768 window to be user friendly.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to get people to remember the URL, I wouldn't go more than 60. Use words if possible, because it's easier to remember "www.example.com/this-is-the-url" than "www.example.com/179264". If you're trying to get the page indexed, you could probably go more. The spiders look for words in the title too, and some people may be more likely to click on the link if the URL looks readable.

Comment: I've heard about this 'spiders are looking in the URL' theory too many times, but without any proof. For what I tested on one big website I worked at, it makes no difference whatsoever. Care to provide some URL that would prove that it is really used?

Answer (score 0):

When you say "Optimum", I think "Easily Accessible To Users", in which case, I think the shorter the URL, the better.  I would think 20-30 characters maximum, in that case.