# limitation of url

Tags: asp.net

is there any limitation for url?how many characters can take the maximum url? thank u.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/179264/what-is-the-optimum-limit-for-url-length-100-200 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051485/what-is-the-character-limit-on-url http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1185739/asp-net-mvc-url-routing-maximum-path-url-length

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the maximum length of a URL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This depends on the browser you are using.

From [RFC 2616 (rfc2616) - Hypertext Transfer Protocol -- HTTP/1.1](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2616.html)

> The HTTP protocol does not place any a
>   priori limit on the length of    a
>   URI. Servers MUST be able to handle
>   the URI of any resource they    serve,
>   and SHOULD be able to handle URIs of
>   unbounded length if they    provide
>   GET-based forms that could generate
>   such URIs. A server    SHOULD return
>   414 (Request-URI Too Long) status if a
>   URI is longer    than the server can
>   handle (see section 10.4.15).
>
> ```
>   Note: Servers ought to be cautious about depending on URI
> ```
>
> lengths
>         above 255 bytes, because some older client or proxy
>         implementations might not properly support these lengths.

[Maximum URL length is 2,083 characters in Internet Explorer](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/208427)

> Microsoft Internet Explorer has a
>   maximum uniform resource locator (URL)
>   length of 2,083 characters. Internet
>   Explorer also has a maximum path
>   length of 2,048 characters. This limit
>   applies to both POST request and GET
>   request URLs.
>
> If you are using the GET method, you
>   are limited to a maximum of 2,048
>   characters, minus the number of
>   characters in the actual path.
>
> However, the POST method is not
>   limited by the size of the URL for
>   submitting name/value pairs. These
>   pairs are transferred in the header
>   and not in the URL.

From http://www.boutell.com/newfaq/misc/urllength.html

> Firefox (Browser)
>   After 65,536 characters, the location bar no longer displays the URL in Windows Firefox 
>   1.5.x. However, longer URLs will work. I stopped testing after 100,000 characters.
>
> Safari (Browser)
>   At least 80,000 characters will work. I stopped testing after 80,000 characters.
>
> Opera (Browser)
>   At least 190,000 characters will work. I stopped testing after 190,000 characters. Opera > 9 for Windows continued to display a fully editable, copyable and pasteable URL in the 
>   location bar even at 190,000 characters.
>   Apache (Server)
>   My early attempts to measure the maximum URL length in web browsers bumped into a server > URL length limit of approximately 4,000 characters, after which Apache produces a "413 
>   Entity Too Large" error. I used the current up to date Apache build found in Red Hat 
>   Enterprise Linux 4. The official Apache documentation only mentions an 8,192-byte limit 
>   on an individual field in a request.
>
> Microsoft Internet Information Server
>   The default limit is 16,384 characters (yes, Microsoft's web server accepts longer URLs 
>   than Microsoft's web browser). This is configurable.
>
> Perl HTTP::Daemon (Server)
>   Up to 8,000 bytes will work. Those constructing web application servers with Perl's 
>   HTTP::Daemon module will encounter a 16,384 byte limit on the combined size of all HTTP 
>   request headers. This does not include POST-method form data, file uploads, etc., but it > does include the URL. In practice this resulted in a 413 error when a URL was 
>   significantly longer than 8,000 characters. This limitation can be easily removed. Look 
>   for all occurrences of 16x1024 in Daemon.pm and replace them with a larger value. Of 
>   course, this does increase your exposure to denial of service attacks.

Answer (score 1):

Check this thread of Stackoverflow [What is the maximum length of a URL in different browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-an-url)

Maximum URL length is 2083 characters in Internet Explorer
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/208427

Maximum URL length is 65000 characters in Mozila Firefox
http://support.mozilla.com/tiki-view_forum_thread.php?comments_offset=0&comments_threadId=0&comments_parentId=153230&comments_threshold=0&thread_sort_mode=commentDate_asc&forumId=1&time_control=3600

Answer (score 0):

it  depends on browser : for ie max characters is 2083 - http://support.microsoft.com/kb/208427