# Google Static Map API - Long URL

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-static-api

I generate URL for calling Google Static Map API but in sometime my url is very long (>2048).
How can I solved this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do anything if the URL is too long. It is by design of the web browser.

See this question [limitation of url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1496080/limitation-of-url)

If static maps API isn't helping you to achieve your task, you might want to take a look @ other [Google Maps APIs](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/index.html)

Comment: I try to call static map with POST method but google not able this way.

Comment: Yes. AFAIK, Static Maps API only supports GET.

Answer (score 6):

You can encode your Polylines and make them shorter .

**Here is the example which can help you how to short your Polylines**

I am using the php library to short the length 
here is the link of library https://github.com/danmandle/encoded-polyline-stitcher

if you use this library

```
(51.838245,-111.834991|51.833179,-111.83503|51.831007022306,-111.8232751234|51.838244686875,-111.82327418214)  =  (atk{HtwqiTt^FpLmhAgl@)
```

Here important point is if you use short url you have to use **"enc:"** keyword

```
(fillcolor:0xAA000033|color:0xFFFFFF00|51.838245,-111.834991|51.833179,-111.83503|51.831007022306,-111.8232751234|51.838244686875,-111.82327418214)  =   (fillcolor:0xAA000033|color:0xFFFFFF00|enc:atk{HtwqiTt^FpLmhAgl@)
```

**The Library is available for other  languages as well if you are not using php  .**

I hope that it helps others

Comment: using encoding we lose precision so if you need precision for more than 5 decimal places then encoding will not work for you. As we totally lose the shape with encoded path

Answer (score 3):

If your url includes polylines you can encode them and make them much shorter. Here's Google's explanation of it, you'll then need to look around for an implementation in whatever language you're using.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/utilities/polylineutility

Answer (score 2):

Recently, in August 2016, the URL limit has been changed to 8192 characters in size.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/static-maps/intro#url-size-restriction